# How can I add an IF statment into an SQL WHERE condition like this?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not so into DB and I have the following problem working on a **MySql** query that need an **IF** condition into the **WHERE** statment.

I need this IF condition because the where statment have to be different in base to a country id retrieved by the query itself. I try to explain you what I need in details.

This is my query (that is not working):

```
SELECT
    LCZ1.id                                          AS localization_id,
    LCZ1.description                                 AS localization_description, 
    CNT.id                                           AS country_id,
    CNT.country_name                                 AS country_name,
    CNT.isActive                                     AS country_is_active,
    RGN.id                                           AS region_id,
    RGN.region_name                                  AS region_name,
    PRV.id                                           AS province_id,
    PRV.province_name                                AS province_name,
    DST.id                                           AS district_id, 
    DST.district_name                                AS district_name,
    SCT.id                                           AS sector_id,
    SCT.sector_name                                  AS sector_name

FROM Localization                                   AS LCZ1
LEFT JOIN Country                                   AS CNT
     ON LCZ1.country_id = CNT.id
LEFT JOIN Region                                    AS RGN
     ON LCZ1.region_id = RGN.id
LEFT JOIN Province                                  AS PRV
     ON LCZ1.province_id = PRV.id 
LEFT JOIN District                                  AS DST
     ON LCZ1.district_id = DST.id
LEFT JOIN Sector                                    AS SCT
     ON LCZ1.sector_id = SCT.id

WHERE
     (LCZ1.country_id = (SELECT LCZ2.country_id FROM Localization AS LCZ2 WHERE LCZ2.id = 5))

IF(LCZ1.country_id = 1)
BEGIN
AND
     LCZ1.country_id is not null
END

IF(LCZ1.country_id = 2)
BEGIN
AND
     LCZ1.country_id is not null
END
```

As you can see the **WHERE** condition start with this:

```
WHERE
     (LCZ1.country_id = (SELECT LCZ2.country_id FROM Localization AS LCZ2 WHERE LCZ2.id = 5))
```

basically I am selecting the **LCZ1.country_id** value performing a second select query that works by localizations_id. I am specifying a localization retrieving its country_id that is used as value of this where condition. It works fine.

Then I need to use this retrieved value to add some **AND** clause to my **WHERE** condition. The **country_id** can be only 1 or 2.

So,

if the retrieved **country_id** value is 1 --> add an AND condition.

if the retrieved **country_id** value is 2 --> add another ADD condition.

How can I fix my query and correctly handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an inner join with the the proper ON and AND clause avoiding where

```
SELECT  ......

FROM Localization                                   AS LCZ1
LEFT JOIN Country                                   AS CNT
     ON LCZ1.country_id = CNT.id
LEFT JOIN Region                                    AS RGN
     ON LCZ1.region_id = RGN.id
LEFT JOIN Province                                  AS PRV
     ON LCZ1.province_id = PRV.id 
LEFT JOIN District                                  AS DST
     ON LCZ1.district_id = DST.id
LEFT JOIN Sector                                    AS SCT
     ON LCZ1.sector_id = SCT.id

INNER Localization LCZ2 ON LCZ1.country_id = LCZ2.country_id 
         AND LCZ2.id = 5 AND LCZ1.country_id = 1 AND  LCZ1.country_id is not null
```

Comment: Ok but...how to handle the second case (contry_id = 2)

Comment: looking to your code seems that in both case the other condition is  LCZ1.country_id is not null so just add  another AND  .. answer  updated ..

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `IF` statements, you just need to rethink your `WHERE` clause a little.

Since you are wanting to add the `LCZ1.country_id is not null` predicate whenever LCZ1.country_id is 1 or 2, you could reformulate that to simply check that LCZ1.country_id is one of the required values:

```
AND LCZ1.country_id in (1, 2)
```